# Svg image does not display using <use /> tag

Tags: reactjs, svg

I'm trying to display a svg image using  tag. But it does not display at all.

```
import cart from '../../assets/icons/cart.svg';
<svg
   width='24'
   height='24'
   xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
   xmlnsXlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
   >
    <use xlinkHref={cart} />
</svg>
```

This is what is getting rendered

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> The `<use>` element takes nodes from *within the SVG document*, and duplicates them somewhere else.

Because your svg isn't even in the document yet, you can't use the `use` element in this way.

Instead import it as a react component and just render it.

```
import { ReactComponent as Cart } from "./cart.svg";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <svg
      width="24"
      height="24"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    >
      <Cart />
    </svg>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit wandering-surf-27qrz]

Or import and render your svg in the defs section, giving it a unique id, then refer to it using the `<use>` tag.

```
import { ReactComponent as Cart } from "./cart.svg";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <svg
      width="196"
      height="24"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    >
      <defs>
        <Cart id="mySymbol" />
      </defs>
      <use href="#mySymbol" fill="blue" x="0" />
      <use href="#mySymbol" fill="red" x="30" />
      <use href="#mySymbol" fill="green" x="60" />
    </svg>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit dry-https-bjpk1]